# How to convert list of string to list of dictionary in Python

Tags: python

i have list of items like this:

```
["{'Collaboration':5,'Communication':5,'Creativity':4,'Critical Thinking':4}", "{'Collaboration':5,'Communication':5,'Creativity':5,'Critical Thinking':4}"]
```

Each item is a dictionary string. How to convert list of string to list of dictionary out of this. I need a final result like this:

```
[{'Collaboration':5,'Communication':5,'Creativity':4,'Critical Thinking':4}, {'Collaboration':5,'Communication':5,'Creativity':5,'Critical Thinking':4}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import ast and use literal_eval. That does the job.

```
import ast
lst = ["{'Collaboration':5,'Communication':5,'Creativity':4,'Critical Thinking':4}", "{'Collaboration':5,'Communication':5,'Creativity':5,'Critical Thinking':4}"]
res = [ast.literal_eval(x) for x in lst]
print(res)
```

Comment: Its converting but when i try to loop through the items in the list its saying its a type of string not dictionary. i have to cast it to dictionary? if  so how would i do that?

Comment: Can you give a little code sample of what you do/want to do? which loop doesn't work?

Comment: If I print type(x) for x in res, then I get <class 'dict'> as answer. Which specs are you running?

Comment: Sorry i ran a wrong code so got that error.. All good. Everything worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should use `json.loads`for this. Your strings use single quotes for encapsulating string. For JSON you have to replace them with double quotes.

```
import json
l = ["{'Collaboration':5,'Communication':5,'Creativity':4,'Critical Thinking':4}", "{'Collaboration':5,'Communication':5,'Creativity':5,'Critical Thinking':4}"]
result = [json.loads(x.replace("'", '"')) for x in l]
```

Comment: I am getting error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'`

Comment: If I paste the code to python it works for me. Can you give it a shot?